# We should have a better dupe target for questions about pronoun order

Tags: discussion, duplicates

We receive a large number of questions about the proper use of pronouns, which in turn means that many of these questions are closed as duplicates.

These aren't *all* duplicates of one another, though: there are actually several topics involved. It’s true they’re related, but they’re not all the same, and the topic is confusing enough that I think it’s a good idea to focus on one main topic per question (and to have a separate question for each topic, so that people can write detailed answers that aren’t too long).

I think we should have a better dupe target for **questions about the order of pronouns in coordinate noun phrases** (in particular, the “me/I last” rule). By "better" I mean "more focused on this particular issue."

- We just got a question about this: [Is "I and he" just as correct as "He and I"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358684/is-i-and-he-just-as-correct-as-he-and-i) I marked it as a duplicate of the following question:
- [Should I put myself last? "me and my friends" vs. "my friends and me" or "my friends and I"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/my-friends-and-i-vs-my-friends-and-me-vs-me-and-my-friends). That question was originally titled “Should I Put Myself Last ("me and you" vs "you and I")?” However, it was later edited on Oct 9 '12  to “'My friends and I' vs. 'My friends and me' vs. 'Me and my friends'”. I actually prefer the original title. Since the edit, it has attracted some answers that don’t actually address the original question about word order at all, such as https://english.stackexchange.com/a/102869/77227 and https://english.stackexchange.com/a/102874/77227.
- [Me and X or X and me?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138478/me-and-x-or-x-and-me?noredirect=1&lq=1) is another earlier question focused on the issue of order, but it was marked as a duplicate of the preceding question.

We already have dupe targets that specifically address case in various circumstances.

**Case of pronouns in coordinate noun phrases.**

- [Which is correct: "you and I" or "you and me"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7188/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me). It’s clear what this question is about, and it addresses a single rule.

**Case after the copula.**

- ["It is me" vs. "It is I"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30336/it-is-me-vs-it-is-i)

**Case in sentence fragments.**

- ["Who wants ice-cream?" — Should I say "(not) I" or "(not) me"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/who-wants-ice-cream-should-i-say-not-i-or-not-me).

So I think it's best if our dupe target for pronoun order *doesn't* focus on the issue of case, which is well-covered elsewhere. This seems to have been the original intention of the OP, but I'm unsure what to do now that the title has been edited for so long and it's accumulated several answers about case.

What's the best way to deal with this situation?